# How to create style in C# code and pass it to xaml in WPF for windows?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I need to create this style using c# code to generate dynamic points for polygon instead of static ones in xaml tags.

```
 <Style  x:Key="Mystyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid  >

                            <Polygon  Points="0,0 0,100 50,200" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                         Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: What you're really asking is how to create the ControlTemplate in code, since all the style does is assign the template. Maybe you should change your question's title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        //Control Template .. We cannot add children to the Control Template Directly

        ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));

        //These points you can set Dynamically as your requirement
        PointCollection points= new PointCollection(new List<Point> { new Point() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, new Point() { X = 0, Y = 50 }, new Point() { X = 100, Y = 200 } });
        var polygon = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Polygon));

        //You can also set Binding rather than static color for fill
        polygon.SetValue(Polygon.PointsProperty, points);
        polygon.SetValue(Polygon.FillProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink));

        //ContentPresenter
        var contentPresenter = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
        contentPresenter.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty,"this is content Presenter");

        //Grid
        var grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
        grid.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
        grid.AppendChild(polygon);
        grid.AppendChild(contentPresenter);
        controlTemplate.VisualTree = grid;

        //Style
        Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TemplateProperty, controlTemplate));
        this.Resources.Add("SomeKey", style);

        //Initialize
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 <Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource SomeKey}"/>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help you to give the idea how to do. And yes you can set all bindings in code behind like Fill of polygon and Content of ContentPresenter .

> Note It is Recommended to use Xaml for creating Templates . As in your problem all what you want is dynamic Points of Polygon . Its better You bind Points property of Polygon rather than creating entire Template in CodeBehind.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating style in code, i would suggest you to have `property in your class and bind your points dependency property with that property` if you don't want the points to be pre-defined in xaml. That's where the `Binding` comes handy.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this suggestion - could you expand on that with some sample code?